# Food Replicators

Tags: star-trek

What happens to all the glasses, cups, dishes and eating utensils that get created when people use the food replicators on the enterprise? There are over 1000 people on the star ship that use the food slots. Doesn't the star ship get cluttered?

Answer (score 0):

They put them into the replicator to be turned back into energy for later use;

From [DS9 : The Ascent](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/507.txt)

> **SISKO :** *I'm afraid Jake's going through a phase of his own.*
>
> (a beat)
>
> *I don't know what's so difficult about **putting a dirty plate back in the replicator.***

and [DS9 : Hard Time](http://www.st-minutiae.com/academy/literature329/491.txt)

> **KEIKO** : *Make sure to put your plate in the replicator.*
>
> **MOLLY :** *Okay.*
>
> **Molly picks up her plate and puts it in the replicator. It disappears...**

[image: Molly Replicator]